# Confirmation that I am not training on test set here

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and just wanted to clarify that I am not training on the test set if I don't call for the optimization node in the graph.

Here is an optimizer node;

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate)
opt_operation = opt.minimize(mse)
```

Here is my training step. Just wanted to clarify that only the nodes in the square brackets are being computed; `opt_operation` is being called so weights are being updated in the model?

```
_,yPred_,loss, score = sess.run([opt_operation,yPred,mse,diceScore],
                                 feed_dict={x:batchX,y_:batchY,learning_rate:lr})
```

Finally here is my test step which doesn't call `opt_operation`.

```
loss,score = sess.run([mse,diceScore],
                      feed_dict={x:batchX,y_:batchY})
```

It's not training in this final `sess.run` step correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, correct.
The training step is executed only when `opt_operation` is performed.

Your last step:

```
loss,score = sess.run([mse,diceScore],
                  feed_dict={x:batchX,y_:batchY})
```

Evaluates only the `mse` and the `diceScore` tensors: no optimization is done.